# Adding Torque layer using createLayer instead of createVis in CartoDB.js?

Tags: carto

I have two tables in CartoDB, one is a fixed layer with locations of restaurants in a city. The other layer has data about the locations where police had to go because of fights for example (say 112 calls) that happened in the city during a one year period.

Because I want to create my own basemap I have been using the `createLayer` function in CartoDB.js to display the restaurants. This works fine. But next I want to add a Torque map of the 112 calls on top of this. However, when I do finally get the Torque map to work, the other layer of the restaurants is no longer visible.

What should I do to make both layers visible?

Below a short version of the code I am using now, which only shows the Torque layer (also, in this version there is no time slider visible, which I hope will become visible once I get both layers working):

```
// initiate leaflet map
map = new L.Map('map', { 
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 11
})

// load the base map
L.tileLayer(mapURL, {
    attribution: '...'
}).addTo(map);

var CARTOCSS_TORQUE = {...};
var torqueLayer = new L.TorqueLayer({
            user       : 'username',
            table      : 'table_name',
            column     : 'column',
            countby    : 'count(cartodb_id)',
            resolution : 2,
            steps      : 300,
            blendmode  : 'multiply',
            animationDuration: 90,
            map: map,
            cartocss   : CARTOCSS_TORQUE
        });

cartodb.createLayer(map, layerURL)
          .addTo(map)
          .done(function(layer) {
              ...make a small SQL query change...
          })
          .on('error', function(err) {
             console.log(err);
          });

torqueLayer.addTo(map);
torqueLayer.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Torque visualization with the Torque library and Leaflet alone, you do it the way you are starting out. If you use CartoDB.js, it has a lot of the logic to make it simpler for you. You don't ever actually have to create the Torque object, just tell CartoDB you want a new 'torque' layer,

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      type: "torque",
      order: 1,
      options: {
        query: "",
        table_name: "monkey_jump",
        user_name: "andrew",
        tile_style: 'Map { ' 
                   +'  -torque-frame-count:19; ' 
                   +'  -torque-animation-duration:2; -torque-time-attribute:"layer"; ' 
                   +'  -torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)"; ' 
                   +'  -torque-resolution:4; -torque-data-aggregation:linear; } ' 
                   +'#monkey_jump{ ' 
                   +'  comp-op: lighter; marker-opacity: 0.9; ' 
                   +'  marker-line-color: #FFF; marker-line-width: 0; ' 
                   +'  marker-line-opacity: 1; marker-type: ellipse; ' 
                   +'  marker-width: 12; marker-fill: #FF2900; }'
        }
    })
```

Here is a working example,

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/9095945

Comment: Thank you, this works (sorry for my late reply)! I just placed this statement below the first `createLayer` and now both layers are visible. Just one thing, my time-attribute is a date and the slider is not showing a date format (for example it shows "07/44188"). How can I change this to show the data (with day) in the slider?

Comment: And one other small thing. When I try to also load a jquery library, the cartodb.mod.torque.js gives the error that there is no method `slider` and the Torque layer fails to load (although the other static layer does load)

Comment: be sure you load the jquery library before the CartoDB.js library. CartoDB.js will load jquery on its own, so I often just use the one it loads. The issue with dates was an error in the lib, it should be fixed already